# Error with backend canister WARN: Building canisters before generate for Motoko

Tags: reactjs, motoko, dfinity

I used the motoko playGround and my backend is working well in playground.

Motoko Playground [URL](https://m7sm4-2iaaa-aaaab-qabra-cai.ic0.app/?tag=3267306482)

But somehow with same code my project backend is getting failed. Getting below error.

```
WARN: Building canisters before generate for Motoko
```

Also backend url generated as below.

```
http://127.0.0.1:4943/?canisterId=be2us-64aaa-aaaaa-qaabq-cai&id=bkyz2-fmaaa-aaaaa-qaaaq-cai
```

Error Image as mentioned below.
[image]